# c# deserialize mutliple Json into same list

Tags: c#, json, list, serialization

I have a Api link that returns this [Json structure](http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/iron/1). In the code I request this Api link and then deserialize it into a list. This is done without problems. But if the Api returns more than 50 "counts" it creates another page. How do i get around to loop through all pages and add everything to the existing list?

In the case i linked there will be 38 pages. All need to be added to the list.

Call

```
    // spidyApiUrl = http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/iron/1
var spidyApi_idByName_result = api_Handler.objFromApi_idToName(spidyApiUrl);
```

Function with the return

```
public RootObject objFromApi_idToName(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader);
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                //return serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonReader);
                RootObject rootObject = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonReader);

                if (rootObject.count > 0) { return rootObject; }
                else { return null; }

            }

        }
```

And ofcourse i also have the `get; set;` classes.

How do I loop through all pages (if mutliple pages exist, which doesnt have to) and add these to the same object list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need continue downloading the data until `page == last_page`
As you get each page of data you then add the new set of `results` to the original rootObject's `results` property with AddRange

I also changed the url that gets passed into the function from

```
http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/iron/1
```

to

```
http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/iron
```

This allows me to add the page numbers to the url to get all the pages

```
http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/iron/1
http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/iron/2
.....
http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/iron/38
```

Code:

```
public class Result
{
    public int data_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int rarity { get; set; }
    public int restriction_level { get; set; }
    public string img { get; set; }
    public int type_id { get; set; }
    public int sub_type_id { get; set; }
    public string price_last_changed { get; set; }
    public int max_offer_unit_price { get; set; }
    public int min_sale_unit_price { get; set; }
    public int offer_availability { get; set; }
    public int sale_availability { get; set; }
    public int sale_price_change_last_hour { get; set; }
    public int offer_price_change_last_hour { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int last_page { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        objFromApi_idToName("http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/iron");
    }

    public static RootObject objFromApi_idToName(string url)
    {
        RootObject rootObject = null;
        RootObject tempRootObject = null;
        int page = 1;
        do
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + "/" + page);

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader);
                var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                //return serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonReader);
                tempRootObject = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(jsonReader);

                if (rootObject == null)
                {
                    rootObject = tempRootObject;
                }
                else
                {
                    rootObject.results.AddRange(tempRootObject.results);
                    rootObject.count += tempRootObject.count;
                }
            }
            page++;
        } while (tempRootObject != null && tempRootObject.last_page != tempRootObject.page);
        return rootObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reponse! This returns a `The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.` on `WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();` but i dont know why, the url I check when the error is promted is correct.

Comment: I changed the start url to "http://www.gw2spidy.com/api/v0.9/json/item-search/iron" without the "/1" 
In the function I then add the page number I need, this could be why you get an error

Comment: Would you mind helping me with another related problem? I have to check to check if these values exist in another Api link, if not do nothing but continue looping, if yes add them like the same but in another list.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Web API?  If so, could you try something like this?

```
public RootObject objFromApi_idToName(string url)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("<your uri here>");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("<uri extention here>");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string jsonStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var deserializedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<your model class here>>(jsonStr);
                return deserializedResponse;
        }
    }
```